# An Introduction to Simplifying Radicals

Tags: radicals

How would I simplify 30 radical 45?

Neither number is perfect square, I don't think. So I'm confused as to how to do it.

Comment: Observe $\sqrt{45}=\sqrt{9\cdot 5}=\sqrt{9}\cdot\sqrt{5}=3\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: If you have meant $30\sqrt{45}$

$45=5\cdot3^2\implies\sqrt{45}=3\sqrt5$

Answer (score 1):

$$30\sqrt{45}
\\
=30({3\sqrt{5}})
\\
=90\sqrt{5}$$